# Need help formatting text file into a complex nested loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I'm learning as I go here with python. Im Working on a project to make a nested dictionary like below from some router configs that I am looping through and outputting to a text file: Any direction would be helpful. I plan to do a conversion on the IPs in the VRF list later using ippadd mod..(text file may or may not have secondary for each block of code)

interface.txt file output sample im looping over

```
interface Bundle-Ether10023.1622
 description Workstations
 vrf r1320
 ipv4 address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ipv4 address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ipv4 address 10.10.30.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ipv4 address 10.10.40.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
interface Bundle-Ether10023.1618
 description AV_Mgmt
 vrf r1580
 ipv4 address 10.11.10.1 255.255.255.0
```

End goal

```
cfg: {
    "ifcs": {
        "interfaceBundleEther10023_1622": {
            "description": "Workstations",
            "vrf": "r1320",
            "gws": {
                "primary": {
                    "10.10.10.1": "255.255.255.0"
                },
                "secondary": {
                    "10.10.20.1": "255.255.255.0",
                    "10.10.30.1": "255.255.255.0",
                    "10.10.40.1": "255.255.255.0",
                },
            },
            "vrfs": {
                "prefix": [
                    "10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0",
                    "10.10.20.0 255.255.255.0",
                    "10.10.30.0 255.255.255.0",
                    "10.10.40.0 255.255.255.0",
                ]
            },
        },
        "interface Bundle-Ether10023.1618": {
            "description": "AV_Mgmt",
            "vrf": "r1580",
            "gws": {
                "primary": {
                    "10.11.10.1": "255.255.255.0"
                },
                "secondary": {
                    "null": "null",
                },
            },
            "vrfs": {
                "prefix": [
                    "10.11.10.1 255.255.255.0"
                ]
            },
        },
    },
}
```

I am able to get this result but I am stuck here...

```
interfaceBundles = '{
    "interface Bundle-Etherxxxx." : {
        "description": "xxxx",
        "vrf": "xxx",
        "ipv4 address": "xxxx xxxx"
    },
    "interface Bundle-Etherxxxx" = '{   
        "description": "xxxx",
        "vrf": "xxx",
        "ipv4 address": "xxxx xxxx"
    },
}
```

Comment: Is your end goal a JSON file? Please show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a solution does not require "a complex nested loop", which is why it's important for us to see your code so that we can perhaps suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a possible solution to your problem. I don't know which Python version you are using, so my suggestions contains a sequence of if ... elif ... which you could replace with switch ... case ... in newer versions:

```
# Create a dictionary to hold the parsed data.
result = {
    "cfg": {
        "ifcs": {},
    },
}

# Open the file that contains your interfaces.
with open("interface.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as interfaces:
    # Loop over all lines in the file.
    for line in interfaces:
        # Split the content of the line into two parts.
        item, content = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
        # Check the first part of the line against a number of keywords
        # and assign the second part to the matching key.
        if item == "interface":
            # Create a new item with the given structure.
            interface = f"interface {content.replace('.', '_')}"
            result["cfg"]["ifcs"][interface] = {
                "description": None,
                "vrf": None,
                "gws": {
                    "primary": {},
                    "secondary": {},
                },
            }
        elif item == "description":
            result["cfg"]["ifcs"][interface]["description"] = content
        elif item == "vrf":
            result["cfg"]["ifcs"][interface]["vrf"] = content
        elif item == "ipv4":
            tmp = content.split()
            if tmp[-1] == "secondary":
                result["cfg"]["ifcs"][interface]["gws"]["secondary"][tmp[1]] = tmp[2]
            else:
                result["cfg"]["ifcs"][interface]["gws"]["primary"][tmp[1]] = tmp[2]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Unknown item: {item}")
```

As larsks pointed out, it's not clear if you want to produce a json file. If   so, add:

```
import json

with open("result.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
    json.dump(result, output_file, indent=2)
```

Cheers,
Gunnar

p.s. Your example does not contain a "vrfs", but I'm sure you can modify the script to fit these in, too.

Comment: Sorry I did not get back to you with the other code snippets as I am in the middle of a entire network conversion at work. I worked this into my code and got it all working as desired. Much appreciated help here.  My biggest struggle was getting the secondary ips to fall in to the correct part of the dictionary, you hit it out of the park with that as well.